# Search from mysql results in a table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I get the search results from my query into a table and then select a entry to update details in my form?

so I have my form: name, address, tel, postcode, email etc.

I have a search query that search's postcode.

I have a list of results which I then want to select one (select button or something similar) and fill the rest of the information back into my form.

Form looks like this

```
<td><form action="searchresults.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><strong>Find a Active Physio</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100">Physio Reference</td>
      <td width="301"><input name="PhysioReference" type="text" id="PhysioReference" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name of Physio</td>
      <td><input name="Physio" type="text" id="Physio" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contact Number</td>
      <td><input name="Number" type="text" id="Number" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td><input name="PhysiosAddress" type="text" id="PhysiosAddress" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Postcode</td>
      <td><input name="postcode" value="" type="text" id="postcode" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Physios Email</td>
      <td><input name="PhysiosEmail" type="text" id="PhysiosEmail" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form></td>
```

Search results like this (need to get them into a table please)

```
<?php

require_once('auth.php');

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Physio"; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select database.
   mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
   mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

    if(!isset($_POST['postcode'])) {
      header ("location:index.php");
     } 
     echo "<p> Results </p>" ;
 $search_sql = "SELECT * FROM `Physio` WHERE Postcode like '%" . $_POST['postcode'] . "%'";
 $search_query = mysql_query($search_sql);

    while ($search_rs = mysql_fetch_array($search_query))
    {
   echo $search_rs['Reference'] . '<br>';
   echo $search_rs['Physio'] . '<br>';
   echo $search_rs['Postcode'] . '<br>';
   echo $search_rs['Line1'] . '<br>';
   echo $search_rs['Tel'] . '<br>';
}
if (!empty($search_rs))
{
echo "<p> Results Found </p>" ;
}
else
{
echo "<p> No Results Found </p>" ;
}

   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  echo"<table><tr>" ;
  echo '<th>Reference</th><th>Physio</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Line1</th><th>Tel</th></tr>';
    while ($search_rs = mysql_fetch_array($search_query))
         {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo "<td>".$search_rs['Reference'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>".$search_rs['Physio'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>".$search_rs['Postcode'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>".$search_rs['Line1'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>".$search_rs['Tel'] . "</td>";
         echo '</tr>';
         }
  echo '</table>';
```

For learning purpose of building html tables in php

[read this](http://davidwalsh.name/html-mysql-php)

```
    echo "<td><a href="url">".$search_rs['Reference'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: :) , you again :) ! .

Comment: its me again, haha that works and displays it properly. i have just read about the Html table and im going to try add it to the css file i have already.

Comment: ok glad it worked for you :) !. just make sure to accept answer.

Comment: do you know how I would get a single result to populate the fields in my form? like creating a link on the reference number of this table, which moves the data of that row back into the form?

Comment: this can be made by ajax if you want.

Comment: i added how you do in reference column , and then call ajax to bring other.

Comment: that's what ive used before by the looks of it, it puts the reference into the web address and then you pull the details from the database on the other page using the reference in the web address?